# Destroy method does not ask for confirmation in Ruby on Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

To avoid physical deletion of information, I added a "is_active" flag to my Business_Rule model, and modified the destroy method the following way:

```
def destroy
  @business_rule.set_as_inactive(current_login)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to business_rules_url, notice: 'Business rule was successfully deleted.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

I invoke this method through a button:

```
<%= button_to t('Destroy'), @business_rule, confirm: t('Sure'), method: :delete, class: "buttons mid_menu" %>
```

Unfortunately, the confirmation does not pop-up! 
Thanks a lot for your ideas to solve this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use confirm in `data` attribute:

```
<%= button_to t('Destroy'), @business_rule, data: { confirm: t('Sure') }, method: :delete, class: "buttons mid_menu" %>
```